# Android Studio 2.0 breaks ndk build with gradle-experimental plugin

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, android-studio-2.0, gradle-experimental

After updating Android Studio to version 2.0 (stable), the Gradle sync for my project is broken.

Error popup:

```
Android Gradle Plugin Update Required

The project is using an incompatible version of the Android Gradle plugin.

To configure the project, the IDE will update the Android Gradle Plugin to version 2.0.0.

You can learn more about this version of the plugin from this [release notes][1].

-> Update   -> Cancel and update manually
```

Gradle Sync Issue (in the messages view):

```
Error:The project is using an incompatible version of the Android Gradle plugin.
Please update your project to use version 2.0.0.
-> Search in build.gradle files
```

I'm using the gradle-experimental plugin (`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.6.0-alpha5'`) for the ndk build as it has been recommended, e.g. [here](http://ph0b.com/new-android-studio-ndk-support/), thus my build.gradle looks like this (with the `com.android.model.application` plugin) and I cannot simply 'update' to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

def superpowered_path = file('.').absolutePath + "/src/main/jni/Superpowered"

model {

    repositories {
        libs(PrebuiltLibraries) {
            superpowered {
                headers.srcDir "${superpowered_path}"
                binaries.withType(StaticLibraryBinary) {
                    staticLibraryFile = file("${superpowered_path}/lib/${targetPlatform.getName()}/libSuperpoweredAndroid.a")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "APPID"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel 15
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"

            archivesBaseName = "APPNAME-$versionCode-$versionName"

            renderscriptTargetApi 20
            renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-rules.pro'))
                signingConfig = $("android.signingConfigs.releaseSigning")
            }
            debug {
                applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
                versionNameSuffix "-DEBUG"
                signingConfig = $("android.signingConfigs.debugSigning")
            }
        }

        sources {
            main {
                jni {
                    dependencies {
                        library "superpowered" linkage "static"
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /*
         * native build settings
         */
        ndk {
            moduleName = "NDKMODULE-jni"
            cppFlags.add("-std=c++11")
            ldLibs.addAll(["android", "log", "OpenSLES"])
            abiFilters.addAll(["armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a"])
        }
    }

    android.signingConfigs {
        create("releaseSigning") {
            keyAlias 'release'
            keyPassword 'PASSWORD'
            storeFile file('KEYSTORE.jks')
            storePassword 'PASSWORD'
            storeType "jks"
        }
        create("debugSigning") {
            keyAlias 'debug'
            keyPassword 'PASSWORD'
            storeFile file('KEYSTORE.jks')
            storePassword 'PASSWORD'
            storeType "jks"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.a'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    // Android support libs
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'

    // Android Async Http
    // Apache 2.0 http://loopj.com/android-async-http/
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'

    // OkHttp http://square.github.io/okhttp/
    // Apache v2
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'

    // Picasso http://square.github.io/picasso/
    // Apache v2
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

    // Retrofit http://square.github.io/retrofit/
    // Apache v2
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4'
}
```

All I could find on issues with Android Studio 2.0 was about the canary / beta builds and seems to have different problems than this one.
Before the update, the Gradle sync worked as expected. (I've been using the last stable build, 1.5.1 I think?).

I'm hoping for some ideas on how to use the ndk with Android Studio 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using gradle-experimental:0.7.0-alpha1 fixed the Gradle sync for me:
`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.7.0-alpha1'`

Comment: I am getting: Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.7.0-alpha1.
error. Do I also have to change elsewhere?

Comment: you should only have to change it in the project's build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

Using the following for classpath fixed the issue for me.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.7.0'
```